# Does a private query method increase SQL injection attack risk?

Tags: java, sql, security, sql-injection

I've had someone point out that using a private method to handle query execution for all queries done by a single class increases the risk of SQL injection attacks.

An example of this method might look like this (below).  I have omitted some specifics so as not to distract anyone on implementation.

If you want to talk implementation, please feel free to in the comments.  The security review did not comment on the contents of the method, but mainly the fact that it should not be its own method.

Note, queryText is generated from a protected static final string containing SQL text for a prepared statement.  The ?'s in the prepared statement text are set using PreparedStatement's setString (or set whatever) method.  The variables that are set on the prepared statement come into the caller method as strongly typed as possible.

queryText is then passed to the private method.

```
    private ResultSet executeQuery(PreparedStatement stmt) throws SQLException {

    // Declare result set variable
    try{
        try{
            // execute statement and store in variable
        }
        catch(SQLException se){
            // log, close connection, do any special processing, rethrow se
        }

    }
    finally{
                    // This finally block is here to ensure the connection closes if
                    // some special processing (not shown) in the other try generates a runtime exception
        // close connection and statement properly
    }
    // return result set
}
```

The recommended alternative was to basically inline the same code in each method that does a query.

I did not post this to security.stackexchange.com because I believe it qualifies as a specific security programming problem.

I can think of no reason why duplicating this code (from a private method) into many classes would add any protection.  Would it?

Thank you

Comment: SQL injection vulnerability depends on how `queryText` is generated. Also, you're not using `PreparedStatement` as you should. You should prepare the statements once and then just feed it with parameters. The way I see it in your code, you're preparing a new `PreparedStatement` every time. Also, I don't see the necessity of nested `try` blocks in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I never saw the original code.  I'm guessing they probably passed in a prepared statement.  Have updated the code to do this so that we can focus on the method vs. inline question.

Comment: That's a huge change to your code. The way it is now, I don't see a SQL injection vulnerability, since you seem to use `PreparedStatement` the right way. It doesn't matter if the method is declared `private` or `public`.

Comment: Actually, at this point the SQL injection would already have happend, so it doesn't really matter if you pass in a `String` or a `PreparedStatement`. If you constructed the `PreparedStatement` from a manually-built SQL String, it'll be just as bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a central (un-duplicated) place for executing queries is a **good** idea. Both from a code-maintainability and from a security standpoint. Why have code that *could* have problems multiple times? It only means that you'll have to maintain it multiple times!

What seems important to me (and which has changed by an edit of the question) is that it should be as hard as possible to execute hand-built SQL Strings with it.

You could, for example, replace any `String` parameters (which you had initially, but since then replace with a `PreparedStatement`) with a custom enum:

```
public enum SQLQuery {
  QUERY1("SELECT foo FROM BAR", 0),
  QUERY2("SELECT foo from BAR where baz = ?"; 1);

  private final String sql;
  private final int argumentCount;

  private SQLQuery(final String sql, final int argumentCount) {
    this.sql = sql;
    this.argumentCount = argumentCount;
  }

  public String getSQL() {
    return sql;
  }

  public int getArgumentCount() {
    return argumentCount;
  }
}
```

Then you can write your method like this:

```
public ResultSet executeQuery(SQLQuery query, Object... arguments) {
  // implementation left as an exercise for the reader
}
```

This way you can be *pretty* sure that you (or anyone else on your team) don't accidentally passes in a self-build `String` into your method.

<sup>If necessary this approach could be extended to handle different parameter types but for many cases using `setObject()` works just fine.</sup>

For increased modularity you could extract an interface from that enum and allow multiple enums to define queries (for example if you have separate modules in your project). But this has the drawback that malicious (or clueless) developers could use dynamic non-enum implementations of `SQLQuery` to get their manually-built SQL strings into that method.

Comment: Thanks.  This follows my instinct, which is not to duplicate code.  Also appears to address raw SQL string manipulation through use of the enum.

Comment: Also consider a "real" ORM system such as Hibernate or another JPA implementation, because they also make it pretty easy to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities (in addition to providing other useful features).

Comment: One more question though, how does passing in Object arguments to executeQuery provide any more protection against malicious arguments than accepting user input in a caller method?  The values for the Object arguments must ultimately come from a caller, right?

Comment: The idea is to avoid *arguments* to be interpreted as *SQL code*. This is done by handling them differently (building the `PreparedStatement` from the known-good SQL code and setting the possibly-malicous arguments using `set*()`). If the arguments themselves are valid is *not* checked by this mechanism. It just ensures that they are *not executed as SQL code*.

Comment: Also: if you accepted a `PreparedStatement` into this method you couldn't know if that was constructed with one of your known-good SQL statements or from a SQL string that was built with user input.

Comment: If you accept a PreparedStatement and the method is private, can't you be relatively sure it's constructed from known-good SQL statements?  You (or your team) are the only ones writing the caller methods in your class that create the PreparedStatement obj's.  I suppose you may not want to place this trust in your team.

Comment: @Foo: trust is good, but having an API that makes it *easier* to write correct code than to write *wrong* code is even better. Just another case of "defense in depth".

Answer (score 1):

If the query being executed by this method has ingredients required for SQL Injection, then irrespective of `private/public` method, it will impact.

This private method will be invoked by some public method which takes input from either user (or) database. If that input is malicious, private method can't stop it from executing.

Don't use raw SQL strings, always better to use prepared statements.

Comment: Understood.  Please see my first comment on the question.  I don't believe the use of raw sql strings was the issue of concern.

Comment: @Foo: You mean " query execution for all queries done by a single class increases the risk of SQL injection attacks." comment? as far as I know, it is false statement (unless there are other things missing in question).

Comment: Yes, I meant simply the question of placing the execution in a private method vs. inlining it.